# Android camera noise in images

Tags: android, image, opencv, android-camera

When capturing frames with the camera in my Android app the images contain a lot of noise.
Here are 3 frames i have captured with my device if you look at the on the right of these frames you see that every frame has this dark gray noise. I need the frames to be the same if that is possible.

[image: noise in images]

Does anyone know where this noise is coming from and more important how to get rid of it?

```
@Override
public void onFocus(byte[] data) {
    frame = data;
    processFrame();
}

private void processFrame() {
    int height =  mCameraPreview.getFrameHeight();
    int width =  mCameraPreview.getFrameWidth();

    Mat mYuv = new Mat( height + height/2, width, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
    mYuv.put( 0, 0, frame );
    Mat mRgba = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor( mYuv, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4 );

    filter.apply(mRgba);
}
```

In my filter method I make use of OpenCV template matching to find this specific part of the image. The objectDetected method saves the result as an image.

```
    @Override
public void apply(Mat src) {
    Mat match = templateMatch(src, template1, 0.07);

    if(match != null){
        Mat match2 = templateMatch(match, template2, 0.04);
        if(match2 != null){
            Mat gray = new Mat(match2.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(match2, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

            objectDetectedListener.objectDetected(gray, "frame");
```

Comment: Have you tried using several devices to test the results?

Comment: No I have used just one device.

Comment: Can you share the code which you used

Comment: have you taken a picture OUTSIDE of your program to see if it is the camera, or your code causing the noise?  you will need to essentially take a picture of the same situation for comparison.

Comment: No I have not taken a picture outside my program. The problem is that I don't have this device at this location so I'm not able to take a picture now. I can take a picture tomorrow morning that is 15 hours from now.

Comment: I recorded a short video to see if there is any difference. It seems that my app does not use the best resolution available. My app has a maximum of 1280x720 while the video has a resolution of 1920×1080. I don't see any noise in the frames of the video.